# Splitting a string in to multiple value

Tags: java

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String delimiter = "\\s\\d\\.\\s";
        String cl;

        while ((cl = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String split[] = cl.split(" ", 2);
            String name = split[0];
            //System.out.println( name);
            String description = split[1];

            String s[] = description.split(delimiter);

        }

        br.close();
```

trying to read in something like this in and split by the delimiter above

(
.WKS 1. Lotus Worksheet (filename extension). 2. Microsoft Works document (filename extension)). )

However, I get back an empty space and it doesn't put anything in Arr[1] just array[0].

My end goal is to store them with .WKS as key and store the rest of them into a hash table under that key with chaining.

Comment: What is Arr[1] and array[0]? What are the expected values in split[] and s[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making a change to `"\\d\\.\\s"` to the delimiter, this code:

```
String delimiter = "\\d\\.\\s";
String cl =  ".WKS 1. Lotus Worksheet (filename extension). 2. Microsoft Works document (filename extension).";
String split[] = cl.split(" ", 2);

String name = split[0];

String description = split[1];

String splitted[] = description.split(delimiter);

System.out.println("name=" + name);
System.out.println("description" + description);

for (String s : splitted) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

prints

```
name=.WKS
description=1. Lotus Worksheet (filename extension). 2. Microsoft Works document (filename extension)).

Lotus Worksheet (filename extension). 
Microsoft Works document (filename extension).
```

Notice the empty line, this means that `splitted[0]` is empty.  
Is this what you want?

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help.